# If execution order at the same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**I have a problem.. I want my firesphere be created every time i press one of the arrowkeys.**

-It works, but: If ( for example ) i press the down arrow, and then, while down arrow is pressed, i press at the same time another arrow, ( for example ) left arrow, it will not create a firesphere on the left. 
But with the Right arrow, everything works just fine ( because it's first of the if statements ).

-I know that the code works from up to down, and i can't change this. But maybe i can find a way to avoid this, make this work how i want.

( I want the creation of the fireSphere be like in Binding of Isaac: If you press Left it will shoot left, if right, it will shoot to the right, BUT if you press left arrow first, and then, while left arrow is pressed, you press the right arrow, it will shoot to the right. The same thing if you press first right )

( English is my second language, if you don't understand me, tell me! I will try to explain myself better )
Thank you!

```
    if (Input.GetButton("RightArrow") && Time.time > timeToFire)
    {
        timeToFire = Time.time + 1 / fireRate;
        Instantiate(fireSphere, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    }

    if (Input.GetButton("LeftArrow") && Time.time > timeToFire)
    {
        timeToFire = Time.time + 1 / fireRate;
        Instantiate(fireSphere, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    }

    if (Input.GetButton("UpArrow") && Time.time > timeToFire)
    {
        timeToFire = Time.time + 1 / fireRate;
        Instantiate(fireSphere, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    }

    if (Input.GetButton("DownArrow") && Time.time > timeToFire)
    {
        timeToFire = Time.time + 1 / fireRate;
        Instantiate(fireSphere, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe use a switch without break

Comment: I think it is a timing issue - when you press the the button you do timeToFire = Time.time + 1 /fireRate; that means I think (if you press another button - the Time.time is not greater than timeToFire and it does not create your instance

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that you want to only fire into one direction at once no matter how many keys are pressed with priority of the order in your code? And also have a cooldown/fire rate, like 1 shot every second or so?

Comment: Also, about the position and rotation in your code, do you actually change them? Because from that code you use the same for all directions.

Comment: Gunnar B, i want that: If i'm pressing a button like DownArrow, and at the same time i press another button, like Up arrow, i want the code to initialize the fireSphere for the last pressed button ( in this case Up Arrow )

Comment: P.s= No, i don't change position ad rotation :)

Comment: So, if you press right and then down, you want down?

Comment: Correct :) I want that.

Answer (score 2):

This code will allow for having all for arrow keys being pressed and held at the same time with the last of them dictating the direction.

Example:
You press and hold ← → ↓, it will use ↓. If you let go of → and then ↓, it will use ←.

(Also used `Input.GetKey` and `KeyCode`)

```
public float FireRate;

public float NextFire;

private List<KeyCode> keysPressed;

private KeyCode right = KeyCode.RightArrow;
private KeyCode left = KeyCode.LeftArrow;
private KeyCode up = KeyCode.UpArrow;
private KeyCode down = KeyCode.DownArrow;

private void Awake()
{
    keysPressed = new List<KeyCode>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(right))
        AddKey(right);
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(left))
        AddKey(left);
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(up))
        AddKey(up);
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(down))
        AddKey(down);

    if(Input.GetKeyUp(right))
        RemoveKey(right);
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(left))
        RemoveKey(left);
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(up))
        RemoveKey(up);
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(down))
        RemoveKey(down);

    if((Time.time > NextFire) == false)
        return;

    if(Input.GetKey(right) || Input.GetKey(left) || Input.GetKey(up) || Input.GetKey(down))
    {
        NextFire = Time.time + FireRate;
        Fire();
    }
}

private void AddKey(KeyCode k)
{
    keysPressed.Add(k);
}

private void RemoveKey(KeyCode k)
{
    keysPressed.Remove(k);
}

private void Fire()
{
    if(keysPressed[keysPressed.Count - 1] == right)
        Debug.Log("right");
    else if(keysPressed[keysPressed.Count - 1] == left)
        Debug.Log("left");
    else if(keysPressed[keysPressed.Count - 1] == up)
        Debug.Log("up");
    else if(keysPressed[keysPressed.Count - 1] == down)
        Debug.Log("down");
}
```

The only point where this still has that little problem with the order is when you actually press down 2 or more keys exactly at once.

This solution is probably not the most performant because of the list operations, but other options I can come up with right now will have their downsides too or not allow for this flexibility.

Comment: Thank you, but i have a problem with the code:  private void AddKey(KeyCode k)
{
    keysPressed.Add(k);
}

private void RemoveKey(KeyCode k)
{
    keysPressed.Remove(k);
} Gives me a error:  NullReferrenceExeption object reference not set to an instance of an object, i can't figure out what that means.

Comment: It means `keysPressed` is null

Comment: this answer needs an Awake () function with this inside keysPressed = new List<KeyCode>();

Comment: @ChrisH Thats right, though for some reason it works on my end without ever initializing the list.

Answer (score 0):

See the part of your code:

```
if (Input.GetButton("LeftArrow") && Time.time > timeToFire)
{
    timeToFire = Time.time + 1 / fireRate;
    Instantiate(fireSphere, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
}

if (Input.GetButton("UpArrow") && Time.time > timeToFire)
{
    timeToFire = Time.time + 1 / fireRate;
    Instantiate(fireSphere, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
}
```

If you press the keys `LeftArrow` and `UpArrow`, the first condition of both if-statements is met.

I assume that `Time.time` is greater than `timeToFire` in the beginning, so the first statement triggers. In this first statemeht you set `timeToFire` to a value greater than `Time.time` (`+ (1/fireRate)`).

=> This makes the second if-statement impossible to evaluate to true.
Thats just the same as

```
int a = 5;
if(SomeTrueStatement() && a < 10)
{
    a = 20;
}
//This never happens because a is now > 10
if(SomeOtherTrueStatement() a < 10)
{
    //Code
}
```

**Possible Solution:**
I dont know out-of-the-box if you can distinct which key was pressed first, but if you save the last Key pressed when it was only one key pressed, you know, if now 2 keys are pressed, which of them is the later pressed key.

```
[Pseudocode]
if(OnlyOneKeyPressed())
{
    savedPressedKey = SaveKeyPressed(GetPressedKey());
    pressedKey = GetPressedKey();
}
else if(TwoKeysPressed())
    pressedKey = GetAllPressedKeys().Exclude(savedPressedKey);

if(pressedKey == "ArrowUp" && ...)
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my idea was pretty similar to @Gunnar-b 's:

```
    protected List<KeyCode> Directions = new List<KeyCode>();

    protected void Update()
    {
        var hasDirection = TrackKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) || TrackKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) || TrackKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || TrackKey(KeyCode.RightArrow);
        if (!hasDirection)
        {
            Directions.Clear();
            return;
        }

        // Has a direction.  Check "Last" item in list (top of stack) and proceed.
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.identity;
        switch (Directions[Directions.Count -1])
        {
            case KeyCode.UpArrow: // Set Rotation Here
                break;
            case KeyCode.DownArrow: // Set Rotation Here
                break;
            case KeyCode.LeftArrow: // Set Rotation Here
                break;
            case KeyCode.RightArrow: // Set Rotation Here
                break;

        }

        // Instantiate fireball using rotation from above

        Instantiate(prefab, position, rotation);
    }

    protected bool TrackKey(KeyCode key)
    {
        // if key was released, remove each item where the item equals key
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(key)) Directions.RemoveAll(item => item == key);

        // Always adds to end, virtual 'Stack'
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(key)) Directions.Add(key);

        return Input.GetKey(key);
    }
```